# Can't set environmental variables in ZSH using `export`

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, environment-variables, zsh

I've searched high and low and tried several other solutions for this but can't seem to find an answer.

In MacOS, I have iTerm2 set to use zsh as my main terminal, with powerelevel10k theme, and oh-my-zsh managing it, not sure if this info will help, but wanted to include it.

I'm trying to set environmental variables, and it keeps giving me the following:

```
> export $FOO=bar
zsh: bar not found
```

It doesn't matter what the variable or the value is, it continues to tell me `<variable> not found`

As far as I can tell, I may have to modify my `.zshrc` file, but I'm lost at this point because I've tried several different solutions here on StackOverflow, and none of them have fixed it. Any ideas on how I can set env variables?

Comment: Use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not when setting, exporting, etc. Use `export FOO=bar` (note: *no* dollar signs anywhere there).

Comment: *facepalm* I'm new to this, thank you @GordonDavisson

Comment: @GordonDavisson that was the solution, if you want to write it up I'll mark it as the solution here for this question

Comment: This is a common mistake, so it's probably better to mark this as a duplicate. BTW, I strongly recommend running your code through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), as it's good at pointing out common problems (though it misses this particular one).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks! I'll check out that site, much appreciated